# Segfault when trying to write into realloc'd memory?

Tags: c, memory

So I'm trying to modify an open source zork engine to hack in some text-to-speech functionality, and I have to record some strings as they come in. I've decided to go with a simple (and kinda dumb) `realloc`-based string append approach, and much to my surprise, it fails right off the bat. Here's my code:

```
#include "../common/frotz.h"

// frotz.h contains 'typedef unsigned char zchar;'

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// Length of the message, including '\0'
static size_t buf_len = 0;
static zchar* buf = NULL;

static inline zchar* get_buf() {
  if (!buf) {
    buf = malloc(10000);
    buf_len = 10000;
    buf[0] = '\0';
  }
  return buf;
}

void speech_add_string(zchar* str)
{
  if (!strlen(str))
    return;

  zchar* buf = get_buf();
  size_t old_len = buf_len;

  buf_len += strlen(str);
  buf = realloc(buf, buf_len);

  strcpy(buf[old_len - 1], str);  // <-- Failure happens here
}
```

LLDB indicates:

```
(lldb) frame info var
frame #3: 0x00000001000197d5 frotz`speech_add_string(str="RK") + 133 at buf.c:31
(lldb) print buf
(zchar *) $0 = 0x00000001005012f0 ""
(lldb) print old_len
(size_t) $1 = 1
(lldb) print str
(zchar *) $2 = 0x000000010001bf24 "RK"
```

What gives? Usually I try to avoid asking such specific questions, but this time I'm genuinely stumped.

Comment: `typedef unsigned zchar`. Look at the `sizeof  zchar` and see if that gives you any clues.

Comment: `strcpy(buf[old_len - 1], str);` --> `strcpy(&buf[old_len - 1], str);`

Comment: **Always** check the result of `realloc` before overwriting the original pointer. See the man-page! To extend this: always check the result of any function which can report an error before using any values it generates.

Comment: Another problem is that you didn't allocate space for the null terminator

Comment: Although if `zchar` is `unsigned int` then you canot use `strlen` or `strcpy` with it at all, and your compiler should be telling you about this problem

Comment: according to google, the definition is `typedef unsigned char zchar;`  . (you still should get compiler errors about using `strlen` or `strcpy` though - if not then invoke your compiler in conforming mode)

Comment: The buf local variable in speech_add_string shadows the global buf, so after you return from speech_add_string(), the realloc'd buffer is leaked.

Comment: Oh, and the first argument to strcpy() is wrong.  You probably intend for it to be (buf + old_len - 1) or (&buf[old_len - 1]) but neither of those is actually correct.  And the strcpy is probably messing up the contents of buf[], to the extent that they're not already messed up.  But I think the actual thing that's causing your crash is the fact that you didn't allocate space for the null terminator, as M.M says.

Comment: You *think* you modified the global `buf`pointer in `speech_add_string` using `realloc`- But you modified something else...